# LESS - USING [ ] statements

Tags: css, less

I would like to use the following code in a LESS file -

```
.chevron_btn.[aria-expanded="true"]{
```

but it produces an error when compiled - is it possible to implement?

Comment: You have an extra . before your attribute selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra `.`:

```
.chevron_btn[aria-expanded="true"]{
```